# Contact Form 7 to PHP SMS Sender

Tags: php, wordpress, sms, contact-form, contact-form-7

I use a Contact Form 7 form to catch the users telephone number in the field phone to send him a SMS reminder, like this:

```
<p>Your phone number<br />
    [text* phone] </p>

<p>[submit "Send"]</p>
```

In my Wordpress theme's functions I then have the following:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_mail_sent', 'your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function' );
function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function( $contact_form ) {
    $title = $contact_form->title;
    $posted_data = $contact_form->posted_data;

    if ( 'smsservice' == $title ) {

        $phone = $posted_data['phone'];
        require_once 'http://myurl.com/smsservice/send_sms.php';
    }
}
```

And in the link send_sms.php I got:

```
  # Modify these values to your needs
  $username             = 'myusername';
  $pass                 = 'mypassword';
  $gateway_url          = 'api-adress';

  $utf8_message_text    = "This is a test sms!";
  $recipientAddressList = array['$phone']


  $maxSmsPerMessage     = 1; 
  $test                 = false; // true: do not send sms for real, just test interface

  try {

    // 1.) -- create sms client (once) ------
    $smsClient = new WebSmsCom_Client($username, $pass, $gateway_url);
    //$smsClient->setVerbose(true);

    // 2.) -- create text message ----------------
    $message  = new WebSmsCom_TextMessage($recipientAddressList, $utf8_message_text);
    //$message = binary_sms_sample($recipientAddressList);

    // 3.) -- send message ------------------
    $Response = $smsClient->send($message, $maxSmsPerMessage, $test);
```

However, each time I fill out the form it does nothing. Not even send the form. However, from the PHP code I can't seem to find a mistake. Anybody else?

Best regards,
Seb

Answer (score 0):

If you are using version 3.9 or later of Contact Form 7 the posted_data property is deprecated. See below:

```
/* WPCF7_ContactForm object no longer has a posted_data property. */
$posted_data = $contact_form->posted_data; // Wrong.

/* Use WPCF7_Submission object's get_posted_data() method to get it. */
$submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

if ( $submission ) {
    $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
}
```

Also the title property isn't accessible since version 3.9. See below:

```
/* Don't do this, since title property is no longer accessible. */
$id = $contact_form->title; // Wrong.

/* Use id() method instead. */
$id = $contact_form->title();
```

In your case, your function will be:

```
function your_wpcf7_mail_sent_function( $contact_form ) {

    $title = $contact_form->title();
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();

    if ( $submission ) {
        $posted_data = $submission->get_posted_data();
    }

    if ( 'smsservice' == $title ) {
        $phone = $posted_data['phone'];
        require_once 'http://myurl.com/smsservice/send_sms.php';
    }

}
```

To see all changes in Contact Form 7 check the [changelog](http://contactform7.com/2014/07/02/contact-form-7-39-beta/).

Answer (score 0):

Well even i have tried the same but the contact form 7 is not the good option it seems for the SMS alert.

In my case i've used gravity forms which is working perfectly.